# Python 3 CSV writer splitting lines which contain commas

Tags: python, csv

I want to pull a csv for the below url. There is a column where some of the value contain text with commas in them which is causing issues. For example in the columns below the last 2 items should be a single column but are being split

> """SL""","""2019-09-29""","""88.6""","""-0.6986""","""5.8034""","""Josh Phegley""",572033,542914,"""field_out""","""hit_into_play_score""",,,,,14,"""Josh Phegley grounds out"," second baseman Donnie Walton to first baseman Austin Nola.   Sean Murphy scores.  """

My code is as follows

```
import requests
import csv

file_name = 'test.csv'

url = 'https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/statcast_search/csv?all=true&hfPT=&hfAB=&hfBBT=&hfPR=&hfZ=&stadium=&hfBBL=&hfNewZones=&hfGT=R%7C&hfC=&hfSea=2019%7C&hfSit=&player_type=&hfOuts=&opponent=&pitcher_throws=&batter_stands=&hfSA=&game_date_gt=&game_date_lt=&team=OAK&position=&hfRO=&home_road=&hfFlag=&metric_1=&hfInn=&min_pitches=0&min_results=0&group_by=name&sort_col=pitches&player_event_sort=h_launch_speed&sort_order=desc&min_abs=0&type=details&'

req = requests.get(url)

with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, quotechar = '"')
    for line in raw_data.iter_lines():
        writer.writerow(line.decode('utf-8').split(','))
```

I've tried removing `split(',')` , but this just results in each character being separated by a comma. I've tried various combinations of `quotechar`, `quoting`, and `escapechar` for the writed but no luck. Is there a way of ignoring columns if they appear within quotes?

Comment: It’s tough to tell which data is part of which row, is there a way to improve the formatting or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your incoming data is *already* CSV; you shouldn't be using the `csv` module to write it (unless you need to change the dialect for some reason, but even then, you'd need to *read* it with the `csv` module in the original dialect, then write it in the new dialect).

Just do:

```
# newline='' preserves original line endings to avoid messing with existing dialect
with open(file_name, 'w', newline='') as f:
    f.writelines(line.decode('utf-8') for line in raw_data.iter_lines())
```

to perform the minimal `decode` to UTF-8 and otherwise dump the data raw. If your locale encoding is UTF-8 anyway (or you want to write as UTF-8 regardless of locale), you can simplify further by dumping the raw bytes:

```
# newline='' not needed for binary mode, which doesn't translate line endings anyway
with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.writelines(raw_data.iter_lines())
```

Comment: Ha, seems very obvious now that I see this. Thanks for the clear answer